# How to inject dependencies inside an ASP.NET Core Health Check

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, .net-core, health-monitoring

I'm trying to use the new [ASP.NET Code 2.2 Healthchecks](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2018/08/22/asp-net-core-2-2-0-preview1-healthcheck/) feature.

In this [link](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2018/08/22/asp-net-core-2-2-0-preview1-healthcheck/) on the .net blog, it shows an example:

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    //...
    services
        .AddHealthChecks()
        .AddCheck(new SqlConnectionHealthCheck("MyDatabase", Configuration["ConnectionStrings:DefaultConnection"]));
    //...
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
{
    app.UseHealthChecks("/healthz");
}
```

I can add custom checks that implement the `Microsoft.Extensions.Diagnostics.HealthChecks.IHealthCheck` interface. But since I need to provide to the `AddCheck` method an instance instead of a type, and it needs to run inside the `ConfigureServices` method, I can't inject any dependency in my custom checker.

Is there any way to workaround this?

Comment: In one of the [samples](https://github.com/aspnet/Diagnostics/blob/release/2.2/samples/HealthChecksSample/CustomWriterStartup.cs) they use `services.AddSingleton<IHealthCheck, GCInfoHealthCheck>();` to register it. Maybe that already works in the preview for 2.2.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As of .NET Core 3.0, the registration is simpler and boils down to this

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddHealthChecks();
    services.AddSingleton<SomeDependency>();
    services.AddCheck<SomeHealthCheck>("mycheck");
}
```

Note that you no longer have the *singleton* vs *transient* conflict as you use what the engine needs to use.

The name of the check is mandatory, therefore you have to pick up one.

While the [accepted asnwer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52029647) seems no longer to work.

Comment: This doesn't work for me... `services.AddCheck` doesn't seem to exist, and the example doc shows that I need to call services.AddHealthChecks().AddCheck<..>(...) instead.  Right?

Comment: Can you explain this statement: "Note that you no longer have the singleton vs transient conflict as you use what the engine needs to use."  Are you saying the parameters of the Health Check class constructor can be automatically supplied somehow?

Comment: @jschmitter What I meant is this: in the other answers (and I believe in the very first versions of the health library) you were told to explicitly add yourself the check via `services.AddSingleton<MyCheck>` (etc). This is indeed a problem because besides the contract, now the type of dependency (Singleton, Scoped, Transient) is contractual and you cannot change the implementation freely. Instead, by using the `AddCheck` method, you need not to know if it is a Singleton, Scoped or Transient. Is that a little bit clearer?

Comment: @PatrickSzalapski Did you include all the required packages (and are you on netcore 6?)

Comment: @PatrickSzalapski documentation states: `Services.AddHealthChecks()
    .AddCheck<SomeHealthCheck>("mycheck");`
Maybe @Yennefer has a custom extension method?

Comment: @PatrickSzalapski, AddCheck<T> is defined in assembly `Microsoft.Extensions.Diagnostics.HealthChecks`, in namespace `Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection`. The project had these "health"-related package references: `AspNetCore.HealthChecks.SignalR`, `AspNetCore.HealthChecks.SqlServer`, `AspNetCore.HealthChecks.System`, `AspNetCore.HealthChecks.UI.Client`. Does it help?

Answer (score 8):

#### Short Answer

> How to inject dependencies inside an ASP.NET Core Health Check.

If we register our services in a correct order, then `SomeDependency` will be available for injection into the `SomeHealthCheck` constructor, and `SomeHealthCheck` will run as part of the health check feature.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddHealthChecks();
    services.AddSingleton<SomeDependency>();

    // register the custom health check 
    // after AddHealthChecks and after SomeDependency 
    services.AddSingleton<IHealthCheck, SomeHealthCheck>();
}
```

#### More Details

A [comment in the Health Check samples](https://github.com/aspnet/Diagnostics/blob/d1cba1f55bab1e3b206a46cee81eb1583d8732e2/samples/HealthChecksSample/CustomWriterStartup.cs#L22-L26) states that:

> All IHealthCheck services will be available to the health check service and middleware. We recommend registering all health checks as Singleton services.

#### Full Sample

```
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Diagnostics.HealthChecks;

public class SomeDependency
{
    public string GetMessage() => "Hello from SomeDependency";
}

public class SomeHealthCheck : IHealthCheck
{
    public string Name => nameof(SomeHealthCheck);

    private readonly SomeDependency someDependency;

    public SomeHealthCheck(SomeDependency someDependency)
    {
        this.someDependency = someDependency;
    }

    public Task<HealthCheckResult> CheckHealthAsync(
        CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken))
    {
        var message = this.someDependency.GetMessage();
        var result = new HealthCheckResult(HealthCheckStatus.Failed, null, null, null);
        return Task.FromResult(result);
    }
}

public class Startup
{
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddHealthChecks();
        services.AddSingleton<SomeDependency>();
        services.AddSingleton<IHealthCheck, SomeHealthCheck>();
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
    {
        app.UseHealthChecks("/healthz");
        app.Run(async (context) => await context.Response.WriteAsync("Hello World!"));
    }
}
```

This sample is also [available on GitHub here](https://github.com/shaunluttin/asp-net-core-health-check-dependency-injection).

Comment: Thanks for such detailed answer !! I had similar setup but instead of `services.AddSingleton<IHealthCheck, SomeHealthCheck>(); `
I had 
.`AddCheck<MongoDbHealthCheck>("monogcheck", HealthStatus.Unhealthy, new string[] {"monogo"});` and this was throwing exception because it could not initialize the health check. I am a bit confused why it was not working ?  and ofcourse After adding it as service  it worked okay .

Comment: This is a great answer, though a bit outdated (note Henk's answer below) - you can now inject services with any lifetime into health checks, as well as automatically register your health checks using syntax like `services.AddHealthChecks().AddCheck<ApiHealthCheck>("api");`

Answer (score 3):

In addition to Shaun's answer: there is an [open pull-request](https://github.com/aspnet/Diagnostics/pull/466) which will allow to inject services with any lifetime (transient and scoped) into health checks. This will probably land in the 2.2 release.

When you can use transient and scoped services in health checks, you should [register them using a transient lifestyle](https://github.com/aspnet/Diagnostics/pull/466/files#diff-5045d0db21d5793d299ad6d2c2af45b7R115).

Answer (score 3):

Dependency injection for health checks in asp.net core works exactly as it works for any other registered service that is added through `ServiceProvider`.

This means creating your health check as

```
public class Foo : IHealthCheck {
    private ILogger<Foo> _log;
    public Foo(ILogger<Foo> log) {
        _log = log; // log is injected through the DI mechanisms
    }
}
```

And registering (using the new 6 style here):

```
builder.AddHealthChecks().AddHealthCheck<Foo>();
```

So this also means that you can inject the `IServiceProvider` itself and utilise it internally should the need for getting further required services or werid use cases be there.

I am very curious why this is not explicitly stated in the documentation and there are no examples for this, as it is not "obvious". But it clearly follows the classical pattern of everything in the asp.net core land.

Comment: I will probably make a PR to the documentation to add it there, spent whole evening trying to understand from docs if this is the supposed way to go.

Answer (score 2):

I was struggling with this in my ASP.NET Core 3.1 Web API as I followed the typical DI approach described above by calling:

```
services.AddHealthChecks();
services.AddSingleton<IHealthCheck, MyHealthCheck1>();    
services.AddSingleton<IHealthCheck, MyHealthCheck2>();
```

Unfortunately, it seems in ASP.NET Core 3.1 that does not actually work as my IHealthCheck implementations were not being called.

Instead, I had to do the following in Startup.ConfigureServices():

```
services.AddHealthChecks()
    .AddCheck<MyHealthCheck1>("My1-check",
        HealthStatus.Unhealthy,
        new string[] { "tag1" })
    .AddCheck<MyHealthCheck2>("My2-check",
        HealthStatus.Unhealthy,
        new string[] { "tag2" });
```

Then in Startup.Configure(), I also called MapHealthChecks() as follows:

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapControllers();
    endpoints.MapHealthChecks("/hc");
});
```

Comment: So you are essentially not able to DI inject? Is that your point ?

Comment: @jbooker I am pointing out the approach suggested in the documentation I found (which said to use DI) didn't actually work and I had to adjust it as shown.